# How to fix 'Build Failure' or 'failed to load gradle project'

Tags: java, gradle, javafx, gluon-mobile

I'm making **javafx application**, I wanna port it into android package *(.apk)* using gradle but I've got error.

## build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.3.10'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'org.javafxports.jfxmobile'

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

mainClassName = 'Main.main'
version = '8u40'
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')

}

jfxmobile {
    downConfig {
        version = '3.7.2'
        // Do not edit the line below. Use Gluon Mobile Settings in your project context menu instead
        plugins 'accelerometer', 'audio-recording', 'barcode-scan', 'battery', 'ble', 'browser', 'cache', 'compass', 'connectivity', 'device', 'dialer', 'display', 'in-app-billing', 'lifecycle', 'local-notifications', 'magnetometer', 'orientation', 'pictures', 'position', 'push-notifications', 'runtime-args', 'settings', 'share', 'statusbar', 'storage', 'vibration', 'video'
    }
    android {
        applicationPackage = 'org.javafxports.ensemble'
        compileSdkVersion = 28
    }
    ios {
                infoPList = file('src/ios/Default-Info.plist')
                forceLinkClasses = [
                        'com.gluonapplication.**.*',
                       'com.gluonhq.**.*',
                        'javax.annotations.**.*',
                       'javax.inject.**.*',
                        'javax.json.**.*',
                       'org.glassfish.json.**.*'
               ]
    }
}
```

**error message like this**

```
Requested project: C:\Users\IVAN\Documents\NetBeansProjects\testi

  Stack trace:
    org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: Could not execute build using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.0-bin.zip'.
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ExceptionTransformer.transform(ExceptionTransformer.java:51)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ExceptionTransformer.transform(ExceptionTransformer.java:29)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ResultHandlerAdapter.onFailure(ResultHandlerAdapter.java:41)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor$1$1.run(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:57)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
```

Comment: can you show your gradle-wrapper.properties file? I think it has an issue.

Comment: @BhavenShah where is usually gradle-wrapper.properties file location? i'm using plugin 'gradle support' on netbeans. i'm sorry, i'm still learning about this project. there is two gradle file 'settings.gradle' and 'build.gradle' on my project. i'm create 'single gradle project' with netbean IDE. there is no  'gradle-wrapper.properties' file

Comment: just press shit button two times and search this filename. It will show you.

Comment: @BhavenShah file not found

Comment: Usually this means that you had a problem downloading Gradle. You can try removing the gradle cache at `C:\Users\<user>\.gradle\caches` and then trying again. By the way, you should update the jfxmobile plugin version (1.3.17) and Down version (3.8.6).

Comment: @JoséPereda wow. I don't believe it's you. I'm big of fan of you man. Ok I'll try it.

Comment: @JoséPereda you're really awesome, thanks.. It's work.. Thank you...

Comment: Ok, good to know. Anyway, if you are using the Gluon plugin for NetBeans, make sure you have the latest version (2.7.0). Creating a new project should already give you jfxmobile plugin 1.3.17